# How to remove vuetify component class or underline in autocomplete component?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, web-frontend

I used autocomplete component from vuetify. I am going to remove default class of the component or remove the underline of autocomplete component.

[image]

Or going to remove this class:

[image]

Are there any possible ways to do that? Any help is really appreacited! Thank you in advance!

Comment: [ https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/KKyOmNQ ] are you looking for this, then in the style section by putting default class in /*deep*/ you can get this. there may be a better option for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template section, you have to write like this

```
 <v-container fluid>
        <v-row
          align="center"
        >
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-autocomplete
              v-model="values"
              :items="items"
              dense
              chips
              small-chips
              label="Solo"
              multiple
              solo
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
```

In style section you have to write like this

```
.v-text-field.v-text-field--solo:not(.v-text-field--solo-flat)>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

[here](https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/KKyOmNQ) is the live example

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is what I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome buddy <3